# Combining variables in SPSS, if multiple regression is appropriate for likert scale

Tags: regression, spss, likert

Im looking into how different types of coping strategies moderates the relationship between working and suffering parental stress. In total I have 5 hypotheses, of how the variables correlate with each other.

I have used a 41 item questionnaire - a Likert scale - with 5 points (strongly agree ~ strongly disagree). I combined 3 different, already validated, measures:
9 items correspond to one variable - work-family conflict
10 to a different variable - emotion coping
10 to a third variable - problem coping
and 12 to a fourth variable - parental stress

How do I combine the different items into the 4 variables, in SPSS?

I believe factor analysis would not be appropriate as the sample size is only 42.

I have tried to compute a different variable but ended up with blank columns and could not perform any analyses.

Is multiple linear regression an appropriate test for checking the relationship between the variables in this case?

thank you, any thoughts are much appreciated

Comment: While this questions asks about SPSS, the question clearly has a statistical question at its heart -- it's asking about the appropriate kind of analysis to arrive at some single measure, and that underlying issue *is* on topic; given that context it's perfectly appropriate to also seek some hints about how to do that in SPSS.

Comment: sorry, that answer was from me, the OP, I was trying to clarify what I had said.

Comment: ana -- Please edit your question to include your clarification. If you look at the bottom of your post, right under the `tags`, you should see an 'edit' link.